# Second domain on magento files not Ponting correctly

Tags: url, server, link

I have 2 different magento stores on 1 admin. I did this by creating shortcuts. Using this article.https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-configure-multiple-magento-storefronts.html

It worked before but in the console I get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)"

Answer (score 0):

I guess your httpd does not follow symlinks outside it's documents root, which is what your setup is trying.

Try to change the setting `System -> Config -> Advanced -> Developer` and then set `Allow Symlinks` to yes.

But this is a bad idea at all and I don't like the approach you've chosen.

Method 2 is way better, but since some server setups doesn't allow `SetEnvIf`, espacially in FCGI mode.

I edited index.php to:

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'default';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
        case 'www.example1.com':
        Mage::run('exmaple1', 'website');
    break;
        case 'shop.example2.com':
        Mage::run('example2', 'website');            
    break;
    default:
        Mage::run('exmaple', $mageRunType);
    break;
}
```